# New Product Or Category with php Pretsashop

Tags: php, function, object, prestashop

I am learning developing to prestashop and i like to add category or product to prestashop with php script.

I know that there is possible way with writing it to database, but i thing that with using function it will be easier.

But I didnt find function for adding product or category.

Could be someone so kind, that he writes me name of function and easy example hot to use it?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For categories, look at /classes/Category.php :

```
$cat = new Category();
$cat->name = 'category name';
$cat->active = 1;
$cat->link_rewrite = Tools::link_rewrite($cat->name);
$cat->id_parent = Configuration::get('PS_HOME_CATEGORY');
$cat->add();
```

Idem for products, in /classes/Product.php

Comment: So I must:
`$cat = new Category($id, $id_category, $name etc.);
$cat->add(1,1,cloathing etc.);`
Is tahat right way? Thank you

Comment: I edited my answer to add more code. It's not tested so you must try & adapt. And take a look at ps_categories table to see all available members.